# how to group the JSON objects based on attribute using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to group the json object based on some date attribute in it. My JSON will look like below

```
{
  "myroot": [{
              "attribute1": 10,
              "date":"2023-08-01",
                },
                {
                  "attribute1": 5,
              "date":"2023-08-02",
                },
                {
                  "attribute1": 100,
              "date":"2023-08-02",
                },
                {
                  "attribute1": 2,
              "date":"2023-08-01",
                }]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to find the sum of attribute1 on date wise. How to do it in python. I am very new to Pandas and NumPy. Thanks in advance
Note: I shouldn't change the JSON structure.